# Declaring a global variable on page initialization

Tags: javascript

I have my web applicatoin initialize method run based upon the page that is loaded.

I need global variables available to only page 1 of 2.  So what I want to do is define and initializ a global variable only if page 1 is loaded.  I'm sure there is a way to do this but I do not know how to.

I pasted my releveant intitialze method and the two global I need.  Currently they are defined and initialized on both page 1 reload and page 2 reload.

I want them only defined an intialized for page 1 reload.

```
/********************
group:globals
********************/

var local = 
  { 
  client_validation:1,
  persistent_element:'hide_1'
  };

window.onload=initialize_page;

/* 
- initialize_page() - function activated on each page load or reload.  Set by global window.onload
*/

function initialize_page()
  {
  var signin_found;
  /*Used to determine which page is loaded / reloaded*/
  if(signin_found=document.getElementById('signin_button')) 
    {
    signin_found.onclick=interface_signin;
    /*Interfaces and bindings*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably overcomplicating this for yourself given that the variables in question are using negligable memory, but anyway the simplest way I can think of is to do this:

```
function initialize_page() {
   if (/* somehow figure out if you're on page one */) {
      window.local = {
         client_validation:1,
         persistent_element:'hide_1'
      };
   }

   // etc.
}
```

Note that you can't declare a variable conditionally by putting a `var` statement inside an `if`: JavaScript doesn't have block scope (only function scope) so it will "hoist" the declaration up outside of the `if`. But in the case of global variables you can get around this because globals are essentially just properties of the `window` object so you *can* create the property conditionally as shown above.

If you later realise that both pages have certain variables in common but also have their own separate requirements you can do this:

```
var local = {
   commonSetting1 : "something",
   commonSetting2 : "something else"
}

function initialize_page() {
    if (/* page one? */) {
       // add page one's settings
       local["client_validation"] = 1;
       local["persistent_element"] = "hide_1";
    } else if (/* page two? */) {
       // add page two's settings
       local["somePageTwoSetting"] = "whatever";
       // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Saying `var local` in the global scope is equivalent to declaring a property called `local` on the `window`. _After_ the assignment statatement `window.local = ...` you should be able to access it directly as `local`, without the `window.` prefix. (You'll find the opposite is true too: globals created with `var somename` can be accessed by `window.somename`.) Try it and see...